# Why is a unit circle with one point removed open in subspace topology on $S$, and not open in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: general-topology

Is this removed point an arbitrary point? Or some particular point? The unit circle is surely closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. To construct a subspace topology $$\mathcal{T}_S = \{ S \cap V: V \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^2} \}$$ How do I find this particular $V$?

Comment: Please, note that the circle with one point removed is NOT closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @RamiroGuerreiro, so it's not open nor closed?

Comment: Correct. The circle with one point removed is not open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, an annoying terminology glitch of topology is that the terms "open" and "closed" are not complements - a set can be neither open nor closed, and a set can be both open and closed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews any hint on how to show it's open on the subspace topology?

Comment: If you consider the circle with one point removed with with the subspace topology it is both open and closed.  Note that the circle itself is open and closed in the subspace topology.  Any subspace is open and closed in the subspace topology.

Comment: @RamiroGuerreiro I think you misunderstand: for a point $p \in S$, $S \setminus \{ p \}$ is open in the subspace topology of $S$ itself. It is also open in the subspace topology of $S \setminus \{ p \}$, but that's another question.

Comment: @Ian Ok. $S$ in the question stands for "the circle" not for "the circle with one point removed"  (which was the space just mentioned).  Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The removed point is arbitrary, it doesn't matter what it is. The point is that the circle is open in its own subspace topology (since it is the intersection of the circle with the entire plane, and the plane is open). Now you remove a point from an open set, but a point is closed, since it is the intersection of that point (a closed set in the plane) with the circle. So you have the complement of a closed set being an open set.

Answer (score 5):

For any point $p$ in $S$, the set $S-\{p\}$ is the intersection of $S$ with $R^2-\{p\}$, and $R^2-\{p\}$ is open in $R^2$, so $S-\{p\}$ is open in $S$. In $R^2$, any neighborhood of any point of $S$ (and hence ,of any point of $S-\{p\}$) contains points not in $S$ (and hence not in $S-\{p\}$).

Comment: I like this explanation.